# unexpected token $ while parsing json

Tags: json

```
{
    "familyVar": {
        "colour": "Black",
        "image": ${image('../../../asd914.jpg')},
        "memory": "32GB"
    }
}
```

Need to convert above format to below one 
because not able to parse that as it gives unexpected token $ and other error on 
jsbin

```
{
    "familyVar": {
        "colour": "Black",
        "image": "${image('../../../asd914.jpg')}",
        "memory": "32GB"
    }
}
                   or 


   {
    "familyVar": {
        "colour": "Black",
        "image": "../../../asd914.jpg",
        "memory": "32GB"
    }
}
```

what i am thinking is that it is not valid json and need to convert it into valid.

Comment: No, you should never convert invalid JSON. You should talk to the person generating the JSON, and explain how specifications and standards work.

Comment: You're not supposed to change the response. It's the responsibility of the json creator to provide the correct one. You can keep on adding check for different different problems.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore and sobrique  is there  any way to make it parsable ?

Comment: Yes, for this specific problem you can replace string.. but it's a very bad idea

Answer (score 0):

json of

```
{
"familyVar": {
    "colour": "Black",
    "image": "${image('../../../asd914.jpg')}",
    "memory": "32GB"
 }
}
```

is valid see:http://www.cleancss.com/json-validator/

Comment: {
    "familyVar": {
        "colour": "Black",
        "image": ${image('../../../asd914.jpg')},
        "memory": "32GB"
    }
}

Comment: use the first one  you paste the other one that i want